# how to write junit and mockito for the below code

Tags: java, junit

```
List<Long> IDList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    try(Stream<TransactionEntity> retailRecordStram = retailRepository.streamAllShareRecords(currentDateTime.substring(0, 6) +"18")){
        RecordCount = 0;
        retailRecordStram.forEach(LambdaExceptionUtil.rethrowConsumer(Entity -> {
            String Record = ReportUtil.generateRecord(Entity);
            FileWriter.println(Record);
    IDList.add(Entity.getRetailTransactionID());//fecting the records and adding in list
            RecordCount++;
        }));
        FileWriter.flush();
```

is there necessary to write junit and mockito for stream

Comment: What do you want to test about it, and what do you think you should mock in it in order to implement that test?

Comment: actually here am fetching the record for database and writting into the file..in list am adding primary key(tranasaction id )of each row(each record fetched).....I want to test.. .but am unable to write test case for this...can anyone help